# Error when installing Forever for node.js server

Tags: node.js, webserver, installation, npm, forever

I'm trying to install Forever for my node.js server but getting following error when `npm install -g forever`, I have `node v0.8.5` and `npm v1.1.46`

```
npm ERR! fetch failed https://github.com/indexzero/read/tarball/refactor-option
l-streams
npm http GET https://github.com/indexzero/read/tarball/refactor-optional-stream

npm ERR! fetch failed https://github.com/indexzero/read/tarball/refactor-option
l-streams
npm http GET https://github.com/indexzero/read/tarball/refactor-optional-stream

npm ERR! fetch failed https://github.com/indexzero/read/tarball/refactor-option
l-streams
npm ERR! Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR!     at errnoException (net.js:782:11)
npm ERR!     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:773:19)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Fil
s (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "forever"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\TJIA\Desktop\Sommarjobb\Extrauppgifter\demo
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.5
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.46
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\TJIA\Desktop\Sommarjobb\Extrauppgifter\demo\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

What could be the problem.

Thanks,in advance

Comment: npm ERR! Error: connect ETIMEDOUT i can see this in the log you have given

Comment: @Sunny: So what's causing that...

Answer (score 0):

This means Github wasn't responding to the http request in time that was specified by npm.